# Passing pointers to async as arguments generates compiler error

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to get my head around async but have not yet found a way to pass pointers.  The aim is to pass a pointer to a pointer so that the thread readTable initialises the pointer to a PostgreSQL connection as shown below.

```
PGconn *conn = NULL;
future<int> resultFuture;

void init
{
    resultFuture = async(launch::async, readTable(&conn));
}

However the compiler complains with:
error: no matching function for call to ‘async(std::launch, int)'
```

Is passing pointers like this not allowed with async?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess

```
void init
{
    resultFuture = async(launch::async, readTable,&conn);
}
```

the second parameters is a `Callable` (which is a function to pointer, or an object with overloaded `operator()` or a lambda function). all the rest are the argument to pass into the callable.

please read `std::async` documentation here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

and about `perfect forwarding` here :
[Advantages of using forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward)